# how to search presence of a webelement multiple times in a webpage using selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How  to check if a particular element is present multiple times in a webpage using selenium java?

Comment: Depends, is the element present at page load? Or do you want to check it on an interval? Please be more clear..

Comment: How about adding your existing relevant code?

Comment: @titli0216 Do you observe any difference when you _check if a particular element is present multiple times in a webpage_?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
driver.findelements(...
```

to search for a list of elements.